# Example of rvalue reference collapsing with "&& &&"

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

When you have templates and references, you can wind up with types like `T & &&`, which get collapsed, according to [some rules](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html).
Basically, everything gets collapsed to `T&` except `T && &&` which gets collapsed to `T&&`

What is a real-world example where the `&& &&` case is triggered?

I found one [artificial example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp161.aix.doc/language_ref/reference_collapsing.html):

```
template <typename T> void func(T&& a);
auto fp = func<int&&>;
```

But in my research so far, I haven't gotten a good sense of when this case realistically comes up.

Comment: Doesn't your first link already provide a realistic example? (Search the page for "Next, suppose that factory<A> is called on an rvalue of type X".)

Comment: @ruakh: I don't think so? That example has something of type `X` as input, which generates a `X&&` in the template, which makes its way to `A`'s constructor as that same type. I didn't see any collapsing of `&& &&` (maybe I missed it, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forwarding when the parameter type is an unconstrained `auto` would be a real world example. For instance, in a lambda.

```
[](auto && arg) {
    return foobar(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
}
```

`decltype(arg)` would be some `T&&` when the lambda is called with an rvalue. The reference collapsing rules would ultimately kick in inside the implementation of `std::forward` and turn `T && &&` into a `T&&` correctly for the return type.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose. I guess I was more looking for a case where *my* code gets a collapsed `&& &&` type, rather than `std::forward` handling it. I guess my takeaway so far is that the case I'm interested in doesn't come up that much in normal application code (:

Comment: @jwd - I mean you can use a poor man's `(decltype(arg)&&)(arg)` directly if you don't fancy writing `std::forward`. Ultimately, it's the same. Reference collapsing happens in both.